# Detect black object on image with lighting effect

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, hsv

I am trying to detect an blakc box on an image with different lighting effects. What I did until now, was to transform my image in HSV colorspace then make a filter range to get the black color, then finding the best polygon contours around that. This works for most of my cases but I came to that image where it does not work and I understand why, but I cannot find a way to make it work.
Let me explain, here is the image:

[image]

This is the mask I get:

[image]

And as you can see on the following image, the red square is not detected when the green square is detected. However by nayed eye it is obvious that the red square is black (grey) and the green square is white. What can I do to do that?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason it doesn't work is because your color threshold doesn't cover this specific case. *To the computer*, the pixel values inside the red box is beyond the accepted threshold, and the pixel values inside the green box is within the accepted threshold; *regardless of what you, as a human, say you see.*

One way you could try to fix this, is by finetuning your threshold further to include the pixels in the red box, and exclude those in the green box.

However, in the very likely scenario that you cannot find any color threshold value that can correctly distinguish your black box from the background image - you have reached the limits of what simple color thresholding can achieve for you.

At which point you will have to experiment with combining other methods for detecting and locating your black box. From post-processing your thresholded values with [Morphological Operation](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-morphological-image-processing-and-its-operations-7bcf1ed11756) and [edge detection and noise removal with filters](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Esyyeung/cvweb/tutorial1.html), to other more advanced techniques for [image segmentation](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Esyyeung/cvweb/tutorial3.html).

Comment: Hello mimocha,

Thanks a lot for your answer. And yes I noticed I cannot find a threshold that satisfied this image. I was just wondering if there are no better colorspace to use to treat this kind of problem. But yes I will look further in image segmentation.

Comment: You could try out other color spaces like LAB or CMYK, but frankly I think even those will have trouble distinguising the shiny white top of the box, and the bottom shadowy wall. You could check out preprocessing your image, like adjusting the contrast, gamma levels and such, but I would personally go for other more powerful approaches instead. Best of luck which either way you choose though.